# Proof verification of Lemma $3.2$ by Sleziak, Toma, Das

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, filters

The paper[I^K Cauchy Functions by Sleziak, Toma, Das](http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/katc/publ/I-K_Cauchy.pdf)

Trying to prove Lemma $3.2$. Faced a little problem at $iv)\implies i).$

> **Lemma $3.2$**. Let $(X, Φ)$ be a uniform space and let $I$ be an ideal on a set $S$. For
>   a function $f : S → X$ following are equivalent.
>
> $(i)$ $f\ $is $I$-Cauchy.
>
> $(ii)$ For any $U ∈ Φ$ there is $m ∈ S$ such that
>   $\{n ∈ S; (f(n), f(m)) ∈ U\} ∈ F(I)$.
>
> $(iii)$ For every $U ∈ Φ$ there exists a set $A ∈ I$ such that $m, n \not∈ A$ implies
>   $(f(m), f(n)) ∈ U.$
>
> $(iv)$ The filter $f[F(I)]$ is a Cauchy filter.

Now $i)\implies ii)$ follows trivially from definitions.Need help proving $ii)\implies iii)\implies iv)\implies i).$

**My Attempts:**

$ii)\implies iii)$

By $ii),$ For any $U ∈ Φ$ there is $m ∈ S$ such that
$$\{n ∈ S; (f(n), f(m)) ∈ U\} ∈ F(I)\\\implies \{n\in S: (f(n),f(m))\notin  U\}\in I$$.

Let $$A=\{n\in S: (f(n),f(m))\notin  U\}\in I$$. Easily, $m,n\notin A\implies (f(m),f(n))\in U.$

$iii)\implies iv)$

For first we need to show that $f\left[\mathcal F(I)\right]$ is a filter.

$1.$ Since $\phi$ is not in $F(I)$ we cannot map a nonempty set to $\phi$ so $\phi\notin f[f(I)].$

$2.$ $f(A)\in f[F(I)]$ s.t $f(A)\subset f(B)\in f(S).$To show $f(B)\in f[F(I)].$Now from set theory it is known that $f(A)\subset f(B)\implies A\subseteq B.$ Which implies $B\in F(I)\implies f(B)\in f[F(I)].$

$3.$ Let $f(A),f(B)\in f[F(I)]$To show $f(A)\bigcup f(B)\in f[F(I)].$ Now, $A,B\in F(I)\implies A\bigcup B\in F(I)\implies f(A\cup B)\in f[F(I)].$ Now, $f(A\cup B)\subseteq f(A)\cup f(B).$ From $2$ this implies $f(A)\cup f(B)\in f[F(I)].$

Thus $f(F(I))$ is a filter.To show it is **Cauchy filter**.Now whatever entourage $U$ we take there exists $A\in I$ s.t $m,n\notin A\implies (f(m),f(n))\in U\implies \exists A^c\in F(I) s.t. m,n\in A^c\implies (f(m),f(n))\in U.$Which implies it's a *Cauchy Filter*.

**(** *Definition of Cauchy Filter used:* Given a uniform space $X$, a filter $F$ on $X$ is called **Cauchy filter** if for every entourage $U$ there is an $A ∈ F$ with $(x,y) ∈ U$ for all $x,y ∈ A$.**)**

$iv)\implies i)$

Chose any $U\in \Phi,$ there is a $A\in F(I)$ s.t $m,n\in A\implies (f(m),f(n))\in U$ i.e $\{m,n\in S:(f(m),f(n))\in U\}\in F(I)\implies \{m,n\in S:(f(m),f(n))\notin U\}\in I$  Now what I need to find is a fixed $m_0\in S$ such that $\{m,n\in S:(f(m),f(n))\in U\}\in I$. Which is that $m_0\ ?$

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose it should be almost immediate that (i) and (iv) are equivalent. (They are more-or-less reformulation of each other.) For equivalence of (i), (ii) and (iii) you might have a look at Proposition 4 of K. Dems: *On I-Cauchy sequences* ([projecteuclid](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rae/1122482121)) or on the relevan part of my [notes on F-limits](http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/sleziak/texty/rozne/trf/iconv/notions.pdf).

Comment: @MartinSleziak : Thanks. I hope my $ii)\implies iii)$ and $iii)\implies iv)$ were correct ?